# What Output will Return the Fetch request if NSPredicate Should Fail

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have two tables with some values .These two tables have one onetoone relations between them.In my first tables contains 70 values and Second table contains 20 values.I Created one fetch request for fetch values from 2nd table based on the condition.These condition is set by using predicate.I added the object return from the request execution in to one array.In some condition the Predicate will became fail in this situation what output will return by the fetch request.How i compare all array object with one class instance.

Comment: Test it. Show your code. How do you expect to compare an array with an instance? You mean check if the array contains the instance?

Comment: @Wain I just print the array objects.when nsspredicate will become fail it shows output like ...( ).how i compare it?

Answer (score 0):

If nothing matches the predicate you will get an empty array back (which is logged as `()`). If there is something wrong with the fetch / predicate then you will get an error (or exception).

You can use the `containsObject:` method on the array to check if a specific instance is in the list of returned objects.

Comment: How I campare () with class instance?ProductPricing *info

Comment: You can't ever compare an array with an instance of `ProductPricing` (well, not in a meaningful way), hence you use `[results containsObject:info]`

Comment: It always give yes..... ProductPricing *info = [_fetchedProductsDataPrice objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];..._fetchedProductsDataPrice  this is my array.How i check the condition.

Comment: Your request makes no sense, if you got `info` from the results array then you know it's there and what it is. What do you want to 'compare' for?

Comment: I want to configure the table cell based on the values return from the array.The Objects in the result array is the dictionary with some keys. The request with successful predicate condition return an object.If the result become empty array () How i give the key path for get the values from dictionary.so i need one comparison and make if else contain for each case

Comment: No, if the array is empty then you have nothing to display so the table row count == 0